# I am getting this error when trying to login using react native and firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I am getting the following error when clicking the log in button. I am not getting any errors inside VSCode..so it appears everything is correct with firebase code. Any suggestions.. I am stuck.[image]

Comment: Can you share your code that you think is causing the issue ?

Comment: const onLogin = async (email,password) => {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            console.log('firebase login successful', email, password)
        } catch(error) {
            Alert.alert(error.code + " - " + error.message)
        }
    }

Comment: That error is coming back when the login credentials are correct. If I enter a wrong password it comes back with the appropriate error that the password is incorrect. So looks like an issue with creating the storage after a successful login

Comment: Does it log 'Firebase login successful'? If yes, then error must be coming after that from something else?

Comment: No it doesn't log a successful message.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage was deprecated by react-native (see: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage).

Check out this thread for details on using firebase with an alternative storage provider: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847. More specifically, according to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847#issuecomment-863411833) post, you should use auth like so:

```
// Import it from your preferred package.
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Provide it to initializeAuth.
const auth = initializeAuth(app, { persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage) });
```